# RavenDB periodic backup bundle + web admin does not persist changes

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm using the latest stable version (3.0.3660) on a VM on Windows Azure and would like to enable period backup. Have tried to enable both local backup and backup to Azure but the GUI doesn't seem to persist the changes. Modal dialog says "Saving..." but nothing more.

Is there a log for this so that I can troubleshoot what doesn't work?

/Erik

Comment: You can enable the console log in the browser (ctrl+shift+j in Chrome) to see if there has been any reported error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it too and the database is non-responsive for several minutes (a co-worker was waiting for tens of minutes). But after waiting a while it actually does something. I configured the Azure backup and that went wrong because it couldn't upload a blob of that large a size. The error was logged and can be found in the studio > status > logs.

Running the server standalone (instead of running as a service) doesn't give any additional feedback either.

Answer (score 0):

Managed it to work by setting "Raven/AnonymousAccess" to Admin and then save the changes, not sure why. Connected with API key that should have full access.